# Error of expression syntax

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
}node;

node *create_cll(node *head,int n);

void main()
{
    clrscr();
    node *head,*p;
    int n;
    printf("Enter the no.of elements:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    head=create_cll(*head,int n);
    getch();
}

node *create_cll(node *head,int n)
{
    node *rear,*p;
    int i;
    head=p;
    for(i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        p=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        scanf("%d",&p->data);
        p=rear;
        rear->next=p;
        p=p->next;
    }
    printf("Circular linked list created..!");
    return (head);
}
```

Code is about creating the circular linked list.
But here I have an error of expression syntax which I am unable to solve.
The error is in the line in the `main()` section where `head` is equalled to the function.
So I need help...

Comment: What main() I cannot see any main() quickly.  Next...

Comment: [sample code](http://ideone.com/DSGbpd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a ptr-to-node, not a node; and remove the `int` keyword:

```
head = create_cll(head, n);
```

In other news:

- It's `int main` in C, not `void main`
- Don't cast the return from `malloc` in C
- Not testing the return value from `scanf` is a sure recipe for surprises.
- `printf` format strings usually have a newline `"\n"` at the end.
- `<conio.h>` and `getch` are not C (even though Mr. Gates wants you to believe that.) Use `getchar()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

`head` is already a pointer

`*head` in your code could be changed to `head` as the method definition follows.